Incorrect Matrix Multiplication Not Producing Segmentation Fault
I am working on homework assignment 1 for the Performance Engineering of Software Systems course on MIT OCW. The assignment involves debugging some C code designed to multiply matrices. Matrices are created using the following function:
matrix* make_matrix(int rows, int cols) {
  matrix* new_matrix = malloc(sizeof(matrix));

  // Set the number of rows and columns
  new_matrix->rows = rows;
  new_matrix->cols = cols;

  // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold the matrix.
  new_matrix->values = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * rows);
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    new_matrix->values[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
  }

  return new_matrix;
}

They are multiplied using the following code:
int matrix_multiply_run(const matrix* A, const matrix* B, matrix* C) {
  
  //tbassert(A->cols == B->rows,
           //"A->cols = %d, B->rows = %d\n", A->cols, B->rows);
  //tbassert(A->rows == C->rows,
           //"A->rows = %d, C->rows = %d\n", A->rows, C->rows);
  //tbassert(B->cols == C->cols,
           //"B->cols = %d, C->cols = %d\n", B->cols, C->cols);

  for (int i = 0; i < A->rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < B->cols; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < A->cols; k++) {
        C->values[i][j] += A->values[i][k] * B->values[k][j];
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

The test file creates matrices, seeds A & B with random values, and then runs them through the multiplier using the following code:
unsigned int randomSeed = 1;

matrix* A;
matrix* B;
matrix* C;

const int kMatrixSize = 4;

A = make_matrix(kMatrixSize, kMatrixSize+1);
B = make_matrix(kMatrixSize, kMatrixSize);
C = make_matrix(kMatrixSize, kMatrixSize);

if (use_zero_matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A->rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < A->cols; j++) {
        A->values[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B->rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < B->cols; j++) {
        B->values[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < A->rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < A->cols; j++) {
        A->values[i][j] = rand_r(&randomSeed) % 10;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < B->rows; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < B->cols; j++) {
        B->values[i][j] = rand_r(&randomSeed) % 10;
      }
    }
  }

matrix_multiply_run(A, B, C);

This should produce a segmentation fault that can be debugged, because A has 1 more column than B has rows. However, when I run it on my M3 Mac, it does not produce a segmentation fault and instead I get the following:
Matrix A: 
------------
    7      9      3      8      0  
    2      4      8      3      9  
    0      5      2      2      7  
    3      7      9      0      2  
------------
Matrix B: 
------------
    3      9      9      7  
    0      3      9      8  
    6      5      7      6  
    2      7      0      3  

Result: 
------------
   55    161    165    163  
  555    1540   1595   1570  
  401    1166   1214   1199  
  173    415    483    457  

Why would this code not produce a segmentation fault when trying to access the nonexistent 5th row of B?

"This should produce a segmentation fault" Segmentation faults are not a guaranteed result of an out of bounds access. They are a potential consequence of that kind of error. The memory that is being accessed by the out of bounds access could have been mapped to the program for a variety of reasons. If this happened, there would not be a hardware fault when access was attempted. Various other symptoms could possibly occur. Or not.

Aside: There is a missing line C->values[i][j] = 0; before the for (int k = 0; … loop.

Malloc is allowed to allocate more than asked for. Sometimes it's just a little more, maybe to get a multiple of 8 bytes. But there might also be cases where it wants to reach a page boundary. Even if this isn't the reason in this case, sometimes corrupting something past the end of a malloced segment doesn't blow up until you try to "free" it. And I'm not seeing much freeing going on here.

Re “This should produce a segmentation fault that can be debugged, because A has 1 more column than B has rows”: Here is an exercise for you: Can you identify any documentation that says if you access an array out of bounds, you definitely will get a segment fault? Is it in the C documentation? The compiler manual? The documentation for malloc on your operating system? If you cannot find documentation saying you this, why do you believe it to be true?

Thanks all. Based on these responses, it sounds like this comes down to me misunderstanding how and when segmentation faults arrive. The assignment says that the code should produce a segmentation fault, and based on my past experience with C, I thought that was what would happen if you tried to access an array out of bounds. However, it sounds like that does not always happen. It sounds like, as others have suggested, the additional memory is being mapped/allocated to the program for some reason.
